# Error en java y Appium "Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new remote session"

Tags: java, android, selenium, maven, appium

Estoy utilizando Appium, Selenium y java para intentar ejecutar tareas automatizadas sobre una aplicación Android, pero al momento de ejecutar mi código desde eclipse me arroja el siguiente error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new remote session
```

Les comparto el código que utilizo

```
import javax.print.DocFlavor.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;

public class AppiumTest {
    
    static AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driverAppium;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        openApp();
    }
    public static void openApp() {
        DesiredCapabilities cap= new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setCapability("deviceName", "Galaxy");
        cap.setCapability("udid", "5dfc0730");
        cap.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        cap.setCapability("platformVersion", "9.0.0");
        cap.setCapability("appPackage", "com.prueba.mexico");
        cap.setCapability("appActivity", "com.prueba.mexico.WelcomeViewActivity");
        driverAppium=new AppiumDriver<MobileElement>(cap);
        URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");
        
        System.out.println("Robot");
    }
}
```

De igual forma las dependencias que agregue en el archivo pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>AppiumTest</groupId>
  <artifactId>AppiumTest</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <description>Pruebas Appium</description>
  <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
            <version>7.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Por ultimo comento que el proyecto se creo como projecto Maven y que ya realice el registro de las variables de entorno, el dispositivo ya está configurado para depuración con USB. Ojala me puedan apoyar con este error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estimado, su problema se debe a que no esta logrando conectarse con su dispositivo le paso un ejemplo que si funciona

```
private static RemoteWebDriver driver;
private static DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();

  capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
  capabilities.setCapability("newCommandTimeout",300);
  capabilities.setCapability("deviceName","Pixel_4_XL_API_30");
  capabilities.setCapability("platformName","Android");
  capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion","11.0");
  capabilities.setCapability("language", "es");
  capabilities.setCapability("locale", "CL");
  capabilities.setCapability("automationName","UiAutomator2")
  System.out.println("Conectando al appium");
  driver= new AndroidDriver (new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),capabilities);  
  System.out.println("Conexion correcta");
```

Estoy usando la version de 7.3.0 de appium java client.

Si quiere agregar una app

```
capabilities.setCapability("app",System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\test\\resources\\app\\app-debug.apk");
```

Saludos.

Comment: Gracias Alex bravo!, me funciono